# Click does not work

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

What is my fault? 
  There is a method in HelloWorldScene.h

```
 void onTouchEnded(Touch *touch,Event *event);
```

The file HelloWorldScene.cpp
I wrote in the Init() method

```
this->setTouchEnabled(true);
```

And here is a description of the method

```
void HelloWorld::onTouchEnded(Touch *touch,Event *event)
{
    CCPoint location = touch->getLocationInView();

    location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);
    location = this->convertToNodeSpace(location);

    CCLog("x =  %f \n y =  %f \n ---------------------",location.x,location.y);
}
```

But click on Windows fail

Comment: Click on windows fails, means what? Are you getting any exception or just touch events are not coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of Touch Event----`TargetedDelegate` and `StandardDelegate`

#### For TargetedDelegate

```
virtual void registerWithTouchDispatcher();  
virtual bool ccTouchBegan (CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual void ccTouchMoved (CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual void ccTouchEnded (CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
```

in your init():

```
this->setTouchEnabled(true);
```

and rewrite `registerWithTouchDispatcher()`

```
void Layer::registerWithTouchDispatcher(){
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this,0,true);
}
```

#### For StandardDelegate

```
 virtual void ccTouchesBegan (CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent);
 virtual void ccTouchesMoved (CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent);
 virtual void ccTouchesEnded (CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent);
```

and in your init():

```
this->setTouchEnabled(true);
```

If you rewrite `registerWithTouchDispatcher()` here. You should call `addStandardDelegate()` in your `init()`.

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addStandardDelegate(this,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

OnTouchEnded is the parent class virtual function
You need to override it
function declaration like：

```
virtual void onTouchEnded(Touch *touch,Event *event);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this.

HelloWorld.h

virtual void registerWithTouchDispatcher(void);

virtual void ccTouchesBegan(CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent);

HelloWorld.cpp

HelloWorld::HelloWorld()

{

this->setTouchEnabled(true);

}

void HelloWorld::registerWithTouchDispatcher(void)

{

CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addStandardDelegate(this, 0);

}

```
 void HelloWorld:ccTouchesBegan(CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent)
{


     CCTouch *touch = (CCTouch *) pTouches->anyObject();
     CCPoint location = touch->getLocationInView();
     location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);
```

// This is for check TouchEvent on Sprite

```
         if(spriteName->boundingBox().containsPoint(location))
                CCLog("Sprite Hit Test");


}
```